# How do calculate IO operations in Cloudant account for Bluemix pricing? (throughput - lookups, reads, writes, queries)

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloudant, price

Coundant standatd plan is written as "100 reads / sec, 50 writes / sec, 5 global queries / sec".
Is this IO/s calculate end-to-end request? Or is it based on the query execution plan?

**Let's give some examples**

Q1.Let's say I use a Bulk operation to create 3 new documents in Cloudant (Bluemix Standard plan).
1 write operation? 3 write operation?

Q2. Query by aggregation(join)-1000 indexed docs with "name, age range, join time" and get as one docs.
1 read? 1000 + 1 read?

Q3. When I am using the standard plan (limit 100 reads / sec), it is assumed that 100 users executed the query in (Q2) at the same time.
How is IO calculated? 1 * 100 reads? (1000 + 1) * reads?
Do some users fail to execute queries because of limitation IO?

There is no data listed properly about Cloudant Price Method.
Can anyone please point me out correctly?
I want to know exactly how the standard plan calculation is measured.

**It would be better if you could add a calculation example and answer!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also answered here, https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/525190/how-do-calculate-io-operations-in-cloudant-account/

1. Bulk operations currently count as 1 W, regardless of the number of docs it contains.
2. A query is a request to a URL that has one of _design, _find or _search, again unreated to the number of documents actually involved. Note that some of these API endpoins (search) are paged, so it would be 1 Query per requested page of results.
3. I assume that by "100 users" you mean 100 concurrent connections using the same credentials, as Cloudant's rate limiting is applied per account. If so, the sum total of requests are counted towards the limit. When that bucket is full, any further requests will be cut off, and failed with a 429: Too Many Requests HTTP status code.

As an example, let's say you have a Standard account where you've set the rate limit to allow 100 queries per second. You have 100 concurrent connections hitting _find repeatedly, each query returning 1000 documents. Cloudant will allow 100 queries per second, so on average each of your connections will get 1 query per second fulfilled, and any attempts to push harder than that will results in 429 http errors. With 10 concurrent connections, on average each will get 10 qps etc.

Cloudant rate limits at the http level. No splitting of bulk ops into the constituent parts take place, at least not yet.

Documentation for how this all hangs together can be found here: https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/Cloudant?topic=cloudant-pricing#pricing"

Comment: Excellent answer, Josh :)

Comment: Thank you for uploading both! I didn't know where to get the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The [Cloudant offering in the IBM Cloud Catalog](https://cloud.ibm.com/catalog/services/cloudant) has a link to the documentation. In the docs is a [description of the plans](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/Cloudant?topic=cloudant-ibm-cloud-public#standard-plan) with additional [examples](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/Cloudant?topic=cloudant-pricing#pricing). The docs also have [sections that explain how read and write operations are calculated](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/Cloudant?topic=cloudant-ibm-cloud-public#provisioned-throughput-capacity).

The [http code 429](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/Cloudant?topic=cloudant-http#http-status-codes) is returned by Cloudant to indicate too many requests. The documentation discusses this fact and there are code samples on how to handle it.

Comment: Cool! I'll check the detail [scenario](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/Cloudant?topic=cloudant-ibm-cloud-public#-_all_docs-)!